# How to Parse XML from a URL using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

Im learning how to parse XML elements into an html document.

This takes a url with an xml, reads the elements but it ain't working...also
I want to take it a bit further but I simply haven't been able to, how can I make it so I read the xml from a url? and use an xml element as filename to create an html document using a template?

////EDIT this is what I tried! /////EDIT/////EDIT/////EDIT/////EDIT/////EDIT/////EDIT

I tried this just for the sake of me knowing what Im doing(...apparently nothing haha) so I could echo if the information was right....

```
<?php

 $url = "http://your_blog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss";
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
 print_r($xml);

?>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It seems like this is NOT your full code and you are prematurely ending your PHP script (got `?>` anywhere?) You also forgot a `;` after your URL.

Comment: @h2ooooooo tried a more coventional approach but it still ain't working..... I put the url on my browser and it works(copy/paste just in case) but still getting a blank page in return(Updated the code..once more)

Comment: Are you sure that blogspot allowed you to download data from other sources than your local server? Do you get an error?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I get nothing, just a blank page.... :/

Comment: Is `error_reporting(E_ALL);` set?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39937/discussion-between-user1876553-and-h2ooooooo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, "cross-domain" requests would be forbidden by web browsers, per the same origin security policy.

However, there is a mechanism that allows JavaScript on a web page to make XMLHttpRequests to another domain called Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).

Read this about CORS:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Check this article out about RSS feeds:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp

Comment: Seems to me the xml document is in the same domain though.

Comment: No no no, it ain't, you see, I want to read an RSS feed, which is on xml.

I want to read the xml, and create an html document from it using one of the elements inside....

Comment: @user1876553 You can't do that from another server unless you run it through your backend first (so instead of Client -> RSS, it'd be Client -> Server -> RSS). Check the link the elliospizzaman posted.

Comment: @h2ooooooo no, I think you guys are misunderstanding me. I read the rss(my own) feed, you get the information, right? Im trying to read it and create a file with the name of an element but that file is using a template. which has some other stuff...

Comment: @h2ooooooo changed my code for you guys to understand a little more of what Im trying to do